# Problem when adding foreign key to existing table

Tags: sql

I'm trying to test adding the foreign key to an existing table as below:

```
    create table calc(x int, y int);
    create table test(a int, b int);
    alter table test add foreign key(a) references calc (x);
```

When executing the commands, it said "near "foreign": syntax error (1)".

I would expect it would add "a" as the foreign key, referring to the "x" in table calc. However, it turns out to be a "syntax error. I try several online SQL editors, all with the same response.

Would you please help?

Many thanks!

Patrick

Comment: a foreign key needs an index on the other table, so even if the syntax is correct, it wouldn't work in your case as column x is neither unique or primary key

Comment: For `a` to become a foreign reference of the key `x`, then `x` needs to be a key  in the first place, but it isn't. Make `x` a key first, then try again.

Answer (score 2):

Syntax it probably is; but, even if you fix it, master table has to have primary or unique key that can be referenced from a detail table.

You didn't specify database you use (SQL you tagged is a *language*); this is Oracle example, just to show that it works when properly used.

```
SQL> create table calc(x int primary key, y int);

Table created.

SQL> create table test(a int, b int);

Table created.

SQL> alter table test add constraint fk_test_calc foreign key(a) references calc (x);

Table altered.

SQL>
```

Comment: The above is also ANSI/ISO SQL standard compliant!

Answer (score 1):

You may try to add the foreign key when creating the table `test`

```
create table calc(x int, y int);
create table test(a int, b int, FOREIGN KEY (b) REFERENCES calc(x));
```

It is also a good practice to set the first column as primary key.